# I am getting a 404 Not Found error when trying to hit a Jersey 2 service

Tags: http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0

I am creating a Jersey 2.x Service using servlet 3.1 without any web.xml
My pom is given below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>testex</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testex Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>testex</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have configured the service using @ApplicationPath resource config given below:

```
 package com.testex.service;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class TestexResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public TestexResourceConfig() {
        super();
        registerClasses(TestexService.class);
    }
}
```

And my service is given below:

```
package com.testex.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.testex.config.Config;
import com.testex.config.ConfigLoader;
import com.testex.provider.ProjectDetailsProvider;
import com.testex.provider.VersionsProvider;
import com.testex.provider.bean.Project;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("/rest")
public class TestexService {
    private final Config config;

    public TestexService() {
        super();
        config = ConfigLoader.getConfig();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getDefaultProjectId")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDefaultProjectId() {
        return Response.status(200).entity(new Gson().toJson(new Project(String.valueOf(config.getProjectId()))))
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getProjectDetails")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getProjectDetails(@QueryParam("projectId") int projectId) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(new Gson().toJson(new ProjectDetailsProvider().getProjectDetails(projectId)))
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getProjectVersionDetails")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getProjectVersionDetails(@QueryParam("projectId") int projectId) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(new Gson().toJson(new VersionsProvider().getVersionsForProject(projectId)))
                .build();
    }
}
```

On deploying it to Tomcat 8 on context root "testex", i hit the below URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/testex/resources/rest/getDefaultProjectId
```

But I get a 404 Not Found error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out. All I needed to do was add the below dependency to my pom and all works like a charm now:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```